# Using Subquery Table in FROM on another subquery

Tags: sql, database, oracle

Basically I want to do something like this.

```
SELECT * 
FROM TABLE, (SELECT * FROM TABLE2) SUBQ
WHERE TABLE.SOMETHING IN (SELECT DISTINCT COL FROM SUBQ)
```

I want to know if it's even possible  to call that subquery table in my `FROM` on another subquery, and if it is, how to do it.

This is a simplified example (my queries are too long), so I'm not looking into another way of rewriting it that doesn't use the subquery in the `FROM`.

Comment: Can you provide some sample input and results data?  Your query, as written, seems unlikely (you are filtering the left table by values in the right, but then keeping all rows in the right table even if they don't match).

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is called [common table expression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_table_expression), it uses the `WITH` SQL keyword.

Of course if this can be refactored to use a temporary table or an (indexed) view it would be much better / more performant and it would serve multiple execution streams (if they all need access to the same data).

If different execution streams do not need to have access to the same data then creating many many temporary tables or views (while also trying to avoid name collisions) is less optimal and the CTE is more useful.

Comment: This does seem to be what I'm looking for. I'll check it out.

Comment: In some RDBMSs you can rely on the fact that the database has a query cache. Even though the query string is verbosely repeated many times it's results will be computed only once and then retrieved from cache (this is the case for MySQL for example). It's still ugly and repetitive but it works "just as fast".

Comment: @MihaiStancu "*..I down voted because..*" -- actually I don't care if you do. You don't need to say it. Citing reason is already enough `:)` Anyway, I think you are right. Rereading the question again, "*.if it's even possible to call that subquery table in my FROM on another subquery*" -- it's recursive. `WITH` is the key. I deleted my answer `:)`